# Xpath to select text from a child node and current node at once

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and I got to this point where I'd like to extract the text from a list with the following HTML structure:

```
u'<div id="someId">'
u'<p><strong>Text1:</strong> next to text 1</p>'
u'<p><strong>Text2:</strong> next to text 2</p>'
u'<p><strong>Text3:</strong> next to text </p>'
u'</div>'
```

so I'd like to get just the text:

> Text1: next to text1
>
> Text2: next to text2
>
> Text3: next to text3

I want to extract the text with XPath as much as possible, I've been trying to use some XPath predicates without resolving my issue.

with

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="someid"]/p/text()').extract()
```

I don't get the text for the strong tag within P

any help will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you were close:

```
'//*[@id="someid"]/p//text()'
```

This will get you a `list` with all the text inside that `p` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of "//"

Comment: my pleasure @jack.the.ripper